# Index scan instead of a Seek

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I added a new computed column on my table:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD DATAORA_STOCK AS (Data_stock + Ora_Stock)
```

Where `Data_Stock` type is `char(8)` and `Ora_Stock` type is `char(6)`.

After I created a new *nonclustered* index in this `DATAORA_STOCK` column:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MyTable_DATAORA_STOCK] ON MyTable
(
    [DATAORA_STOCK] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

When I execute these 2 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE DATAORA_STOCK = @Data1
```

And:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE DATAORA_STOCK >= @Data1
```

I have two different execution plan. First query seek on IX_MyTable_DATAORA_STOCK and after make a Key Lookup.

Why second perform a Scan Index on clustered index?

With `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` it works well and the actual (not estimated) execution plan it's right.
Unfortunately I can't modify query text because it's called from application... 
I have updated statistics on my table but nothing change.
The exact query text is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyView
WHERE DatAgg+OraAgg >= @Data1 AND DatAgg+OraAgg <= @Data2
```

Where `DatAgg+OraAgg` is `DATAORA_STOCK` in original table (the view is only a projection of MyTable),and `DATAORA_STOCK` is a computed column.

Comment: Probably becasue the >= will get a large percentage of the rows.In sql server is a threshold where when a condition gets more than 30% of the rows the optimizer will switch to an index scan rather than an index seek.

Comment: @Mihai - The tipping point is much lower than that. Often just a couple of a percent.

Comment: @MartinSmith I stand corrected,any official or non official docs though?

Comment: @Mihai - See Kimberley Tripps series of examples here http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-tipping-point-query-answers/

Answer (score 2):

Because the index isn't covering and it estimates that the number of rows returned by the

```
  WHERE DATAORA_STOCK >= @Data1
```

will cause so many lookups to retrieve the missing column values that it is cheaper just to scan the whole thing.

If the estimates are wrong you can try using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to get it to sniff the value of `@Data1` (and if the estimates are still wrong update the statistics on that column)